# Sorting HTML menu item by name?

Tags: html

How can I sort a menu item list by name?

```
    <menu name="whatever">
        <item name="List 2" href="#"/>
        <item name="List 1" href="#"/>
     </menu>
```

output:

List1
List2

Comment: Or server side using whatever you generate the page with, depending on the situation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible with the means of HTML only. You probably can try using JavaScript (or some framework on it) if you want do this on client-side. Here is an example for jQuery sorting: http://www.wrichards.com/blog/2009/02/jquery-sorting-elements/